# Node.js Socket.io: io.on ('connection') is not working

Tags: html, node.js, express, http, socket.io

io.on ('connection') doesn't work. I have been looking for an answer to my question for a long time, but I have not found it. I am using Express + Socket.io bundle, so I expected there might be problems. I found in one answer to a question to use express.static, but it didn't help. Vod file in which the server code:

```js
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var PORT = 3000;

var connections = [];

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));

app.get('/', function (request, responce) {
    responce.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    connections.push(socket);
    console.log(connections);
    console.log('New user connected to chat!');
    socket.on('disconnect', function (data) {
        connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1);
        console.log('User disconnected.');
    });
});

server.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log(`Start listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Here is the index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Socket.io chat</title>
</head>
<body>
    Site is working!
</body>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
</script>
</html>
```

My directory tree looks like this:
SocketChat/
  index.js (server file)
  package.json
   package-lock.json
  node_modules/
  public/
    index.html

I remember to restart index.js after changes and the text "Site is working!" it seems to me. What is the problem? Thanks in advance to those who will solve my question. Sorry if I have a silly mistake :|

Answer (score 0):

It was necessary to add to the html page:

```html
<script>
       var socket = io ();
</script>
```